# Matplotlib not working in macOS. shows error. I tried to reinstall everything.but still not working

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code

dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_xcb_connect'

this keeps showing
please help me solve this

Answer (score 4):

The error seems to be `pillow` 9.0.1, a matplotlib dependency. Reverting back to 9.0.0 should solve the error in the meantime.

Pillow issue here: https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/6015